# need help in joining items in an array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I need help in joining two or more consecutive items in array if their length is 1.

For example, I want to change this :

```
string[] str = { "one", "two", "three","f","o","u","r" };
```

To :

```
str = {"one","two","three","four"};
```

Comment: *What have you tried ?*

Comment: We have an expectation here on Stack Overflow that before asking, you make an effort. As part of the question, we expect you to post the results of these efforts. Unfortunately, this questions shows no such thing.

Comment: What is the use-case of the algorithm? Homework or real-life problem?

Comment: @sll - `joining two or more consecutive items in array if their length is 1.`

Answer (score 4):

Using a `GroupAdjacent` extension (such as the one [listed here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/04/21/the-groupadjacent-extension-method.aspx)), you can do something like this :

```
string[] input = ...

string[] output = input.GroupAdjacent(item => item.Length == 1)
                       .SelectMany(group => group.Key 
                                          ? new[] { string.Concat(group) } 
                                          : group.AsEnumerable())
                      .ToArray();
```

If efficiency is a big concern here, I suggest rolling your own iterator block or similar.

Comment: Isn't it only grouping items with `Length == 1`, without taking other items as they are?

Comment: No, it will take the other items as they are. That's the `: group` bit.

Comment: "Untested" is an understatement, it doesn't event compile given the OP parameters.

Comment: @Magnus: It was just missing the `.AsEnumerable()`. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
    private string[] GetCombined(string[] str)
    {
        var combined = new List<string>();
        var temp = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var s in str)
        {
            if (s.Length > 1)
            {
                if (temp.Length > 0)
                {
                    combined.Add(temp.ToString());
                    temp = new StringBuilder();
                }
                combined.Add(s);
            }
            else
            {
                temp.Append(s);
            }
        }

        if (temp.Length > 0)
        {
            combined.Add(temp.ToString());
            temp = new StringBuilder();
        }

        return combined.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: And with an input of   `string[] str = { "one", "two", "three", "f", "o", "u", "r", "five", "s", "i", "x" };` you get?

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer, used in LINQPad :)

```
void Main()
{
    string[] str = { "one", "two", "three","f","o","u","r","five" };
    string[] newStr = Algorithm(str).ToArray();
    newStr.Dump();
}

public static IEnumerable<string> Algorithm(string[] str)
{

       string text = null;
       foreach(var item in str)
       {
        if(item.Length > 1)
        {
            if(text != null)
            {
                yield return text;
                text = null;
            }
            yield return item;
        }
        else
            text += item;
        }

        if(text != null)
            yield return text;
}
```

Output:

> one
>   two
>   three
>   four
>   five

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest and more efficient way is just iterating over the array:

```
string[] str = { "one", "two", "three", "f", "o", "u", "r" };
List<string> output = new List<string>();
StringBuilder builder = null;
bool merge = false;

foreach(string item in str)
{
    if (item.Length == 1)
    {
        if (!merge)
        {
            merge = true;
            builder = new StringBuilder();
        }
        builder.Append(item);
    }
    else
    {
        if (merge)
            output.Add(merge.ToString());
        merge = false;
        output.Add(item);
    }
}
if (merge)
    output.Add(builder.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
string[] str = { "one", "two", "three", "f", "o", "u", "r" };
var result = new List<string>();
int i = 0;
while (i < str.Length) {
    if (str[i].Length == 1) {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(str[i++]);
        while (i < str.Length && str[i].Length == 1) {
            sb.Append(str[i++]);
        }
        result.Add(sb.ToString());
    } else {
        result.Add(str[i++]);
    }
}
```